# Composite Symbol in FlexViewer 2.2

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-flex-api, flex, markers

I have two questions regarding picture marker symbol in flex viewer:

1. How can I make a composite symbol so that users can re-size and drag it. Any example code could help a lot.
2. I have three symbols (2 text and a picture marker symbol) in a composite symbol. A picture marker symbol is drawn where the user exactly clicks on the map. One text Symbol on the right and the problem is with the left text symbol. I am not able to place it on the left side. 
   By setting its x offset property to 0, it centers it self in the picture marker symbol. 
   By setting x offset to negative the result is same as setting it to 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Q2: have you tried the 'placement' property of the TextSymbol?  It allows you to place the text above, below, to the right, to the left or centered.  See the constants and their descriptions at http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/apiref/com/esri/ags/symbols/TextSymbol.html#constantSummary

Comment: I will check it as I git the time. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Hello Svensson, I checked it and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

never seen anything like this as a possibility. In GIS that is. CAD maybe. If you could post some images of the problem and desired outcome, maybe someone could get creative.

Comment: Thanks Brad Nesom. I had solved my first question almost as I had got the clue. My second question is still unsolved. In short I want to say that can I set xOffset property of a Symbol in negative so that it could be brought to the left.